# insert data from pandas dataframe to phoenix table

Tags: python, json, pandas, apache-phoenix

I have a panda DataFrame i can iterate it over the row by

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

similarly, i can create table in phoenix by

```
database_url = 'http://my_ip/'
conn = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (ID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, BARCODE VARCHAR, CATEGORY_ID VARCHAR, DIVISION_ID VARCHAR, ITEM_CODE VARCHAR, TITLE VARCHAR, STATUS VARCHAR ,  MBQ VARCHAR, MOQ VARCHAR, MRP VARCHAR, CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP, UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP)")
```

Here, a column contain value in json format which couldnot get pushed up to the phoenix table

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in Df.values]
cursor.execute("UPSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (ID, BARCODE,CATEGORY_ID,DIVISION_ID, ITEM_CODE,TITLE, STATUS, MBQ, MOQ, MRP, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT)", tuples)
```

But it isnot working

edit: pandas dataframe
[image]

Comment: If it's in JSON format, convert it to a table format. What does your data look like? Can you show a sample?

Comment: i edited the question. any other column can be dummy variable

Comment: Do each of those key-value pairs go into separate columns? Or should the entire contents of `mbq`  go into a single column?